# jQuery resize() event not firing on input resize. Alternate solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

As the title says, the jQuery event resize() is not firing when the width of a input box changes. According to the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/resize/), resize event is sent to the (window) handler. So my question is, what other solution do I have to listen to a resize event.

I'm currently using the transition attribute in CSS, rather than using jQuery animate to alter the inputs width. It's much cleaner and smoother in CSS, so I would like to keep it like so. If anyone has any other solutions, please list them below.

My first attempt was something like this

```
$('input').resize(function() {
    $(this).val('Resize? Nope!');
});
```

Here is a fiddle for the resize event: http://jsfiddle.net/Yw9CT/

Comment: In full, the sentence reads "The resize event is sent to the window element when the size of the browser window changes:", and the example is `$(window).resize(function() {...}`. There is no resize event associated with input elements - reason being, they are not naturally resizable, except (subject to CSS directive) by resizing the window.

Comment: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

Comment: Thank you to the poster above. I'll be taking a look at this, but it seems though that it may or may not be out of date. Thank you!

Comment: Could you not just use jQuery `hover()` in the situation demonstrated in your jsFiddle? Because if `resize()` worked, it would fire after the input was 1px wider (i.e. almost immediately).

Answer (score 0):

The `resize()` method in jQuery is for elements that can be manually resized by the user. By resizing the element using javacript/jQuery, you are not firing any event...

You can either create your own event, or use a `textarea`.

**UPDATE**

After looking at your jsFiddle, this issue is very clear. You are resizing the input using a CSS3 method. This does not trigger any jQuery events, you would be better off handling the animation with jQuery.

Comment: That I understand, hence why I said that I would like to keep using the CSS transition property then having to create a pseudo method in javascript. But it's starting to seem that using animate is my only hope.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/transitionend) event to find out when the CSS3 resize has completed.